# Integrating D3-Chart into existing HTML site

Tags: html, d3.js

I've got a little problem with my homepage.
At first: I'm a newbie at programming and I`m trying to teach myself for about 2 months now. So please consider this when you see what I've done till now ;-)

Well, what's the problem.
I have a php site to connect to my SQL-Server and to collect information which I gather in arrays.

Also, I have created an HTML part under the PHP code where my Homepage is coded.
When I got to the point where I wanted to visualise the data from the PHP-section I entered the D3-script into my existing HTML part in hope the graph will just appear where I placed it. But actually, it doesn't at all. Here my HTML code with d3 script. The only thing I see is still the without the graph homepage.

Is there a problem with the visualisation or is the graph behind my page in the background? And how can I make it appear. Thanks in advance!

Here the HTML-code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" class="shadow">

<header>
  <img src="images/logo_portfolio.png" width="126" height="74" alt="Lorem ipsum" class="floatleft Lorem" />
  <img src="images/Uni_Logo.png" width="35%" height="35%" alt="Lorem ipsum" class="floatright Ipsum" />     
    <br><br><br><p class="tagline">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <br><p class="title">Fahrspuranalyse</p>
</header>

<section id="content">
    <h1>Fahrspuranalyse: Patentpool</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<script>

    // ------------- Variablen für Fahrspur 1 ----------------

    var StartpatentFS1 = <?php echo json_encode($Number[0], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;
    var AnzahlPatenteFS1 = <?php echo json_encode($GesamtPatenteFS1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;  

    // ------------- Variablen für Fahrspur 2 ----------------

    var StartpatentFS2 = <?php echo json_encode($StartpatentNrFS2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;
    var AnzahlPatenteFS2 = <?php echo json_encode($GesamtPatenteFS2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;  

    // ------------- Variablen für Fahrspur 3 ----------------

    var StartpatentFS3 = <?php echo json_encode($StartpatentNrFS3, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;
    var AnzahlPatenteFS3 = <?php echo json_encode($GesamtPatenteFS3, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); ?>;  


    // ------------- Array mit allen Fahrspurinformationen (Länge und Beschriftung) ----------------

    var ArrayAnzahlPatente = [AnzahlPatenteFS1, AnzahlPatenteFS2, AnzahlPatenteFS3];        // Array für die Balkenlänge

    var Fahrspuren_name = [StartpatentFS1, StartpatentFS2, StartpatentFS3];     // Array für die Balkenbezeichnung


    var width = 700;
    var height = ArrayAnzahlPatente.length * 50 + 50;
    var padding = 50;


    var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(ArrayAnzahlPatente)])
            .range([0, 500]);

    var axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(widthScale)
            .tickFormat(d3.format())
            .ticks(5)
            .orient("bottom");

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + padding)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20, 50)");


    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(ArrayAnzahlPatente)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 0)
                .attr("height", 48)
                .attr("fill", "orange")
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50 })
                .transition()
                    .delay(400)
                    .duration(1600)
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return widthScale (d) })
                    .attr("height", 48);        

    canvas.selectAll("text")
            .data(Fahrspuren_name)
            .enter()
                .append("text")
                    .transition()
                    .delay(1800)
                    .ease("linear")                     
                    .text(function(d) { return d; })
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return (10); })
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 50 + 30})
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "14px")
                    .attr("fill", "black");                     

    console.log(ArrayAnzahlPatente);        
    console.log(Fahrspuren_name);


    canvas.append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
                                    .call(axis);                        
</script>

    <form class="pure-form" action="Fahrspuranalyse_Patentpool.php" form style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Zurück">
    </form>  

</section>

<footer> 
    <p>&copy; Lorem ipsum - 2015</p>        
</footer>

</div>
</body>
```

/EDIT: I found out that the problem ist the snippet: `<div id="container" class="shadow">`

How can I make sure that the Chart will be on this container and not below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

This line is doing exactly as it reads - you're appending the graphic to the body of your webpage, so it will appear after the last element to be drawn.

Scripts don't execute the way you think. Just because the script is in that part of the page doesn't mean that it will be executed - and its output drawn - in that section.

The line I pointed at above is telling the script where to draw the chart on the page, so if you add a div to the page where you want the chart drawn:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

...and then change your line to reference it...

```
var canvas = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
```

...you should start to get somewhere.

I haven't verified the rest of your code but hopefully that'll help get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have to admit that I switchted to another solution yesterday since I found googles charts very easy and flexible enough for my needs. So I can't check it that would solve the problem at all. But thanks to your feedback I got a better understanding of how placing works.

Comment: No problem. Google charts are very easy to use and there is an active forum you'll find linked on the main site, so good choice. Good luck!